# TortoiseHg: Push Branch

Tags: mercurial, push, branch, tortoisehg

I am working on some bugs in our code base and I have created separate branches for each bug. I have rebased one of the branches on top of `default`. I generally use the Mercurial plugin for Eclipse and do a push (when I am in the default branch). This pushes my changes on the default branch.

I tried to do the same thing with TortoiseHg. When I press push, the client complains that I am about to create remote heads/create new branches on the server. Is there some way to push only changes on one branch using TortoiseHg?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is via the command-line using `hg push -r .` from the branch with the change you want to push.  See [`hg nudge`](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-09-28-nudge-a-gentler-push/) for details.

That being said, it is also possible via TortoiseHG:

1. Open your Repository Explorer
2. Open Tools->Synchronize
3. Open "Advanced Options"
4. Set "Target Revision" to the changeset that you want to push
5. Select "Push"

This should only push the changeset you specified (along with any parents of that changeset which may be required).  If you limit the changesets that are pushed to those on your default branch, there should be no warning about creating additional heads.

More information (well, not that much) can be found in the [Section 4.9 of the TortoiseHg documentation](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/1.1/synchronize.html).

Comment: These exact steps do not apply to TortoiseHg 6.4. The manual also doesn't show "Advanced Options", but there is "Options": https://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync.html
Is that where it should be, or is it supposed to be with the "Target" checkbox/drop-down?

Answer (score 12):

Here’s another way to do it:

1. Open Repository Explorer.
2. Click **Determine and mark outgoing changesets** (green up arrow button). All your changesets / branches will be marked with an up arrow.
3. Right-click on the changeset you want to push. From the menu, select **Push to here**.

Works the same way as the previous answer, but allows you to select the changeset from the list, without typing or pasting the target changeset id.

Comment: Thanks. You can now even choose "Push / Push selected branch" in 3.