# TortoiseHg 2.0: Push Branch

Tags: mercurial, branch, push, tortoisehg, tortoisehg-2.0

This question is the same as: [TortoiseHg: Push Branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293240/tortoisehg-push-branch), except it is for TortoiseHg 2.0. The old way no longer works. The options are not even there.

Here is the issue: As I work on different bugs, I create different branches for each. How can I push just one branch using TortoiseHg 2.0?

When I go into sync view, and push - I believe it tries to push all my local branches, and ends up aborting - since multiple heads would be created.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The feature exists in TortoiseHg v2, but the interface changed.  In the Sync tab, there is the following menu:

[image: thg sync menu]

1. Enable the "Target" checkbox
2. Select the branch you want to push
3. Push as you normally would